# iOS Application function within AppDelegate for when opened without shortcut

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the following function to detect when my app is opened via a force touch shortcut:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
    print("doing performActionForShortcutItem")
    completionHandler(handleShortcut(shortcutItem))
}
```

Is there another way within my `AppDelegate.swift` file to detect when the application is opened without a shortcut?

Comment: Look at all of the `UIApplicationDelegate` methods. There's several that are called for various triggers that bring up your app.

Comment: @rmaddy - I went through the list, although none stand out to what I am trying to achieve exactly...

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @rmaddy - currently, there are functions within my ViewController that are being called being my AppDelegate is even run. So instead, I am trying to call my main run function that is within my ViewController from my AppDelegate instead. Depending if a shortcut item is used or not, I need to set a variable within my controller and then run a function. The variable is different for each shortcut item, along with being different again if no shortcut item was selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When *activated* via a shortcut, (your app has already been launched, but is not active) `application:performActionForShortcutItem:completionHandler:` will be called.

When *launched* via a shortcut, the `launchOptions` dictionary from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` will contain a key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey`.

**If that key is not present, your application was not launched via a shortcut.**

If you test to see that a value for that key does *not* exist, you will know that your app was not launched via a shortcut.

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` you need something like this:

```
let launchedByShortcut = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey] != nil

if (!launchedByShortcut) {
    // the app wasn't launched via a shortcut
}
```

Comment: Seems to be the right way to to, although an error is thrown when opening the app without shortcuts. http://postimg.org/image/pgc0lm1j5/

Comment: I believe it is probably because `launchOptions` is `nil`, and it's unable to find `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey` of `nil`.

Comment: That's correct. I just updated my answer to handle that case. The `let` now handles the case where `launchOptions` is `nil`.

Comment: Great, works perfectly. Thanks. Will award bounty in 19 hours.